# How to map an input field as different field in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

Suppose I am inserting data in MongoDB as

```
db.collection.insertMany([{username:'Jack',msg:'hello'},{username:'Jenny',msg:'hello world'},{username:'Rose',msg:'Hi howz You'}])
```

now I want this data to be inserted as this:

```
{account_username:'Jack',msg:'hello'}
{account_username:'Jenny',msg:'hello world'}
{account_username:'Rose',msg:'Hi howz You'}
```

and NOT THIS:

```
{username:'Jack',msg:'hello'}
{username:'Jenny',msg:'hello world'}
{username:'Rose',msg:'Hi howz You'}
```

I am using mongoose in my NodeJS code, can I do something in Schema so whenever input is username it will automatically refer to account_username of my defined mongoose Schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using mongoose with mongoDB one can easily do this using mongoose virtual functions functionality, [Mongoose Virtuals](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/virtuals.html)

Mongoose Viruals have Setters and Getters, Which have functionality to define columns with different name